# Global sections of exceptional divisor in normalized blow-up

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, birational-geometry

Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian normal local domain and $I$ an $R$-ideal. Write $X$ for the normalization of $\mathrm{Proj}(R[It])$ and $E$ for the effective Cartier divisor defined by the invertible ideal sheaf $I\mathcal{O}_X$.
We may place suitable hypothesis on $R$ (excellent / essentially of finite type over a field / that completion has no nilpotents) to guarantee that $X$ is of finite type over $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.

One sees from the exact sequence $0 \to I\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_E \to 0$ that $\mathrm{H}^0(E, \mathcal{O}_E) \supseteq R/\overline{I}$, where 
$\overline{I}$ denotes the integral closure of $I$. 
Is it true that $\mathrm{H}^0(E, \mathcal{O}_E) = R/\overline{I}$? I am specifically interested in the case: $\dim R = 2$, $I$ is 
$\mathfrak{m}$-primary and $R$ is *not* pseudorational. (If $R$ is pseudorational, then the answer is positive.)

Any help/reference will be appreciated.

Thanks; Manoj.